# Oracle SQL delete duplicates with for loop

Tags: sql, oracle

I was asked to do a query to remove all duplicates that involve these 6 fields as we want a unique key in this table.

I need to leave the one with biggest ID on the table and delete all the other ones. I came up with the following code following the suggestion of using a for-loop to do it.

```
begin
  for rec in (
      select max(id), attribute, product, partner, pr_group, contact_person, branch, count(1) cnt
        from co_attribute
        where attribute = 100000034 and product = 100252046
        group by attribute, product, partner, pr_group, contact_person, branch
        having count(1) > 1
  ) loop
      delete from co_attribute
        where (attribute = rec.attribute
          or (attribute is null and rec.attribute is null))
          and (product = rec.product 
            or (product is null and rec.product is null))
          and (partner = rec.partner 
            or(partner is null and rec.partner is null))
          and (pr_group = rec.pr_group 
            or(pr_group is null and rec.pr_group is null))
          and (contact_person = rec.contact_person 
            or(contact_person is null and rec.contact_person is null))
          and (branch = rec.branch 
            or(branch is null and rec.branch is null))
          and (max(id) < rec.id)
          ;
      dbms_output.put_line(
  'Deleting duplicates '            || 
  ' |attribute: '    || rec.attribute     || 
  ', product: '      || rec.product     ||
  ', partner: '      || rec.partner     ||
  ', pr_group: '     || rec.pr_group    ||
  ', contact_person: ' || rec.contact_person  ||
  ', branch: '     || rec.branch        ||
  ', id: '       || rec.id          ||
  ', deleting row: '   || sql%rowcount
  );
  end loop;
end;
/
```

The where in the select is just so I don't mess up the entire DB while testing this script. This gives me the following errors:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 22, column 15:
PL/SQL: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
ORA-06550: line 9, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

So I have two questions: first is, how do I solve this issue and is this the most effective way?

edit: removed the id field inside group by

Comment: Change `select max(id)` to `select max(id) as max_id`. Then change `and (max(id) < rec.id)` to `and (max_id > rec.id)` and it should be OK.

Comment: If I was you - I'd delete the rows by rowid, meaning that the cursor should return the rows, which I need to be deleted, that is their ROWIDs, then the delete statement should be quite simple. Also, if it's about billions and billions of records, I'd first extract the unique ones, put them in a separate table, then truncate the original, then insert the unique ones you saved before.

Answer (score 2):

You may use below statement to leave the one with biggest ID on the table and delete all the other ones :

```
delete co_attribute a
 where
   a.id <
   any (select b.id
          from co_attribute b
         where (a.attribute = b.attribute or (a.attribute is null and b.attribute is null))
           and (a.product = b.product or (a.product is null and b.product is null))
           and (a.partner = b.partner or (a.partner is null and b.partner is null))
           and (a.pr_group = b.pr_group or (a.pr_group is null and b.pr_group is null))
           and (a.contact_person = b.contact_person or (a.contact_person is null and b.contact_person is null))
           and (a.branch = b.branch or (a.branch is null and b.branch is null))
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it following a part of the comments and a few changes suggested over here! First I changed `max(id)` to `max(id) maxid` and also `max(id) < rec.id` to `id < rec.maxid` since `maxid` is part of `rec` and not of the delete query!

Thanks a lot for the help!